# this.previousSibling is null

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tree

I am getting error that I dont understand why, if someone with fresh eyes could take a look.

**Everything works as intended**, but console log is giving:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.previousSibling is null

document.querySelectorAll(".fa-minus-circle").forEach(minus => {
             minus.addEventListener("click", function(e){
                this.previousElementSibling.remove();
       // on this line 
                this.remove();
              });
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. add one or more new input fields.
2. try to remove some.

I repeat, it works, and right field is deleted. I don't understand where this error is coming from, its the same with `previousElementSibling` and `previousSibling`. And after inspecting the HTML structure after adding/removing elements, everything seems right.

**Example:**

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".fa-plus-circle").forEach(plus => {
  plus.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var cln = this.previousElementSibling.cloneNode(true);
    this.parentElement.appendChild(cln);
    this.parentElement.querySelector("input:last-of-type").value = "";
    $('<i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 5px;"></i>').insertAfter(cln);
    document.querySelectorAll(".fa-minus-circle").forEach(minus => {
      minus.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        this.previousElementSibling.remove();
        this.remove();
      });
    });

  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="w3-col s3">
  <label for="Mobitel">Mobitel  </label><br>
  <input type="text" class="w3-input w3-border  w3-round" name="Mobitel[]" placeholder="Mobitel" style="width: 88%; display: inline;white-space:nowrap;">
  <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 5px;"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".fa-minus-circle").forEach(minus => {
```

After the first, you add the same event listener again and again to the previous ones. Hence, change it to:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".fa-minus-circle:last-of-type").forEach(minus => {
```

The snippet:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".fa-plus-circle").forEach(plus => {
      plus.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              var cln = this.previousElementSibling.cloneNode(true);
              this.parentElement.appendChild(cln);
              this.parentElement.querySelector("input:last-of-type").value = "";
              $('<i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 5px;"></i>').insertAfter(cln);
              document.querySelectorAll(".fa-minus-circle:last-of-type").forEach(minus => {
                  minus.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                          this.previousElementSibling.remove();
                          this.remove();
                      });
          });

  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="w3-col s3">
    <label for="Mobitel">Mobitel  </label><br>
    <input type="text" class="w3-input w3-border  w3-round" name="Mobitel[]" placeholder="Mobitel" style="width: 88%; display: inline;white-space:nowrap;">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 5px;"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh my my, I would lost hours more trying to figure it out, was looking at everything but that... Thank you.

Comment: And first time it happened to me. Never sow events pile up like this :D And i dont need for each then...